# Wiring for Nest Thermostat No "Auto" fan Hydro-Air

Tags: wiring, thermostat, nest

Currently, my thermostat has G, W, Y and R wires. I have central AC Unit outside, Propane Furnace and an Air Handler in the attic. (Hydro-air) is what I was told.

I tried to install a Nest Thermostat E and everything worked perfect EXCEPT for when the heat turned on the fan wouldn't automatically turn on. I had to turn the setting on the thermostat to "ON" for the heat to flow through the vents. There was no "auto" setting on the thermostat.

When I turn off power to the furnace there is still power to the thermostat so it seems like instead of the furnace powering the thermostat, the air handler powers the thermostat.

Is there a different wiring set up that I should use to "trick" the thermostat into working correctly or do I need to just climb up in the attic and figure out where the wiring comes from and trace the wires from the air handler to the thermostat and/or wires from the furnace to the thermostat

Comment: I'm surprised you have both a furnace and a hydro-air system. My FirstCo hydro-air system does heat via a hot water coil, and cooling via a traditional AC coil - no separate furnace needed.